# multiple-threading javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I know that a lot of people asked about multiple-threading in javascript but none of the answers allowed me to do what I want.

I want to plot different graphs in a web page. However the last graph need long computation time to plot. I am working with multi-dimensional matrices combined with the map function and therefore I think there is no possibility to optimize this part of the code.

What I want to do is to display the page after the computation of the first graphs has finished and display the last graph only when the computation for the last graph finishes. My goal is to avoid the freezing of the window just because of the last graph.

Example: display all the graphs except the last one letting the user scroll through the window to see the different graphs, display a loading message instead of the last one during computation and display it when computation has finished.

I tried to work with generators and yield but it's not working...

Here is my code:

```
function update() {
Promise.coroutine(function* () {
    // plot the first graphs
    plotThemAll(newC,newPV,newEL,newF,newModel,L);
    plotHydrogenProduction(newC,newPV,newEL,newF,newModel);

    //plot the last graph
    var plot = yield generateDataCF();

})().catch(function(errs) {
  //handle errors on any events
})
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Promises and coroutines are just design patterns for managing concurrency. And concurrency != parallelism. If you want real parallelism you need threads. And in the browser that is webworkers.

Comment: See: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers as an intro

Comment: @slebetman You should post that as an answer - ideally with a code sample.

Comment: @Luaan: I'm too lazy to write a non-link answer which is why I posted it as a comment :) Write up an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Browser javascript still only runs on a single thread - there is no multi-threading, plain and simple. However, it doesn't actually hurt all that much - what you could do instead is partition your CPU-intensive work, and split those partitions with e.g. `setTimeout`. This way, the background computation will only take reasonable chunks of the CPU, and the site will stay responsive.

If you are using promises, this is even easier - you just need to yield once in a while. But you still need to understand that **you** have to yield - there is no pre-emptive multi-tasking.

Comment: @Akshay Yup, those would allow true parallelism. They also require a bit different way of thinking, though - although in this case they might very well be the best choice, as long as you can actually afford to use them (that is, you don't need to support any browser that doesn't support web workers).

Comment: Thanks for you for your response. Can just explain me how to use the yield correctly? Should I put it inside the loop or is it ok if i put it before the function that compute the loop (generateDataCF()?

Comment: The problem with web worker is that I cannot interact with the DOM :(

Comment: @IdreesSamim To make it work properly, you need to call it repeatedly, basically. The idea is to give the UI the CPU if it needs it, but keep it for yourself if noöne else needs it. I'm not sure of the exact proper syntax, but that's the gist of it. And actually, not being to interact directly with the DOM is a *great* thing - it shields you from oh so many multi-threading issues; but that's why didn't mention it - it will probably require a more thorough redesign than just using `yield`.